# Installing EE when existing cms site exists

Tags: subdomain, install

Never been in this situation before so just wanted to make sure i do it correctly.

I am developing a new website (with EE), and currently a site/cms (non-EE) already exists on the server. What is the best way to set this up - meaning upload location/development site - so i can work on it without affecting the current site? Do I just create a folder in the root (named eg, new-site) and upload all EE files there, then go through the usual installation? Do i just change the two system_path references to .new-site/system/ or is none of that necessary?

When i am working out pages/segments how would this work without causing any issues/ having to make coding changes after the site is live? (ie, example.com/new-site/template_folder.... )

Is it better to create a subdomain and base url's on that (ie newsite.example.com) rather than just a 'folder'?

After everything is complete, do i just delete/remove the existing site form the root, then move all new site files out of the new-site folder?

Responses are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we usually do is add a folder `ee/` to the root and install everything there. The base url will then be `http://yoururl.com/ee/` and ExpressionEngine will install everything accordingly and will ignore the subdirectory in segments.

When you go live (switch to the root directory) you will have to update the urls in General Configuration as well as any urls that you entered such as File Uploads path, template path, etc. which is usually not that bad. Try to use relative directory paths when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is recommended that you 'll use a separate (second) database so the databases won't merge and you keep your database clean!

Comment: Would never think of using the same db.